Outdoor 3 tiered fountain leaking from base
I have a concrete 3 tier outdoor fountain that leaks from the base.  I think the leak has to be coming from the bottom bowl because everything above falls into it.  We have completely sealed the bowl with a sealant made for water fountains.  I don't remember the name of it but it's like rubber that you paint on.  THE ONLY TIME THE FOUNTAIN LEAKS IS WHEN THE PUMP IS ON!  I also used some E/Fusing 900 silicone putty and completely covered the PVC pipe that the cord runs thru so no water can escape thru the cord hole.  The PVC pipe is completely covered from the bottom of the bowl to the top where the cord for the pump comes out (about 4 inches long). Even though all of this has been done water is still coming out of the very bottom of the pedestal. Again, it only leaks when the pump is running.  How can this be possible?  Any suggestions how to fix this problem would be very much appreciated. I've tried to add a photo but for some reason it's not letting me.

Maybe it is the pipe that supplies water that is leaking or the pump itself?

Please post a photo of the fountain and anything else that may be relevant

Without photos, and a diagram of how the pump is arranged, it's hard to be sure.
But let's assume there is a pump in the bottom bowl, with a pipe that goes through a hole there and up the middle of the fountain.  And apparently the power enters through another hole in the bowl.
Step 1: See if the leak is anywhere in the visible portion of the bottom bowl.   On a very calm day, about an hour after sunrise when the air temperature  is fairly stable, ensure the water is calm and put some drops of food coloring in various places in the bottom bowl.  Watch to see how the food coloring drops spread and move.  If there is no leak, and the day is calm enough, they should just spread slowly and gradually from where they are until the whole bowl is evenly colored.  If there is a leak anywhere you'll see some of the drops drawn to it.
Step 2: If that shows no leak, the leak must be in the riser pipe, up the middle.   Can't say how to fix that without seeing it.  If the fountain is not too big to be turned on its side you can hopefully examine or remove the plumbing up the middle of it.

Most likely there is a split or crack where a flexible line from the pump discharge connects to a solid pipe taking the water to the top of the fountain.
How to get to it?
How to correct it?
We haven't a guess without a pic of the fountain.
